# javascript onclick not working in a form

Tags: javascript

i am trying to change text of a span using onclick of javascript but its not working . Its very simple stuff but i am not sure why its not working

```
<div class="subscribe_block">
   <h3><span>Stay Connected</span></h3>
   <form method="post" action="" name="subscribeForm">
    <span id="message"></span>
    <p><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Id" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="subscribe" onClick='document.getElementById("message").value = "Thank you for subscribing";return false;' /></p>
   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: js code is in onclick

Comment: i tried that as well but it dint work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div class="subscribe_block">
   <h3><span>Stay Connected</span></h3>
   <form method="post" action="" name="subscribeForm">
    <span id="message"></span>
    <p><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Id" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="subscribe" onClick='document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Thank you for subscribing";return false;' /></p>
   </form>
  </div>
```

Use `'innerHTML'` instead of `'value'`.

Answer (score 1):

On the onclick function, try changing,

'document.getElementById("message").value = "Thank you for subscribing";return false;'

to

```
 'document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Thank you for subscribing";return false;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `value` to `innerHTML` as

```
<div class="subscribe_block">
    <h3><span>Stay Connected</span></h3>
    <form method="post" action="" name="subscribeForm">
        <span id="message"></span>
        <p><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" /></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Id" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="subscribe" onClick='document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Thank you for subscribing";return false;' /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `InnerHtml` will set your `Span` text but as it will post back so you will be unable to see anything. Remove form tag then you will be able to see it.

```
<div class="subscribe_block">
```

#### Stay Connected

```
<span id="message"></span>
<p><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" /></p>
<p><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Id" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="subscribe"  onClick='document.getElementById("message").innerHTML= "Thank you for subscribing";return false;'  /></p>
```